# Symmetry sculpting is behaving oddly

Tags: sculpting

After joining and remeshing several objects the sculpting symmetry is suddenly off, as shown in screenshot. I didn't bother placing my model at the center from the beginning so maybe that's the problem. I'm a newbie so I really don't know. I read in another thread that you can recenter your model by changing location and rotation to 0,0,0 but that had no other effect than putting in a weird angle. How do I fix it? I really need symmetrical smoothing to finish my frog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you share the file as it was before you put the toad back in center ? I can't figure out why the angle of the frog changed. Would rotating the frog to have it centered solve the problem ?

Comment: I found a solution here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199959/symmetry-is-mirroring-on-wrong-axis

It's not perfectly symmetrical but it works for what I need it for.

Comment: I would also apply the *Scale* (Ctrl+A) because it's not uniform for your model. It has different values for each axis as you can see in the side panel. This can cause weird stretchings in sculpt mode. The cursor is also deformed to indicate this and you get a warning about this in the status bar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdzqK.jpg